# Gas problem creating Solidity contract with hundreds of pre-populated structs in array

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm creating a time release contract for tokens with a simple struct and stored in a public array:

```
    struct Lockbox {
        address beneficiary;
        uint balance;
        uint releaseTime; // seconds since epoch
    }

    // Numbered lockboxes support possibility of multiple tranches per address
    Lockbox[] public lockboxes;
```

I've reduced the code to add each entry to it's simplest form:

`lockboxes.push( Lockbox( address(0x32...), 1666667, 1635711346 ) );`

This project requires 1000+ of these Lockboxes to be created, but I'm running out of gas after just a few hundred.

Is there another pattern I can use?  Or should I simply create the contract, and use separate transactions to add all the lockboxes?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason behind the need to create 1000+ of these Lockboxes? Is it some kind of airdrop for selected addresses? Do you know all values before the contract deployment? Are there groups of (different) addresses that will have the same `balance` and `releaseTime`? Please edit your question and share more info... When you're filling an array of 1k items (especially multi-word structs; one word is 32bytes in this case), it's always going to be costly. I'm trying to understand the issue to find a way to not have to fill the 1k array but to use less data.